# Large File Storage issue in Gitlab Container

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, git-lfs

I'm running a  `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest` image on my docker container.
The git: push, pull and clone is working file. But when I try to push the lfs objects,
it throws an error stating:
`Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/4), 655 KB | 33 KB/s, done. LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=http) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=<MY_HOST_IP) %!!(string=/root/root.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/d2f0fbf9d84622b2aa4aed401daf6dedb8ac89bb388af02078ba375496a873dc/53918064) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 405`.\

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: '<MY_HOST_IP>'
    ports:
      - "8084:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "22:22"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/gitlab
      - ./logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - ./data:/var/opt/gitlab
      - ./lfs:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/lfs-objects
      - /mnt/storage/lfs-objects:/mnt/storage/lfs-objects  
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 22
        gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true
        gitlab_rails['lfs_object_size_limit'] = 4096  
        gitlab_rails['lfs_storage_path'] = "/mnt/storage/lfs-objects"  
        external_url '<MY_HOST_IP>'  
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_host'] = '<MY_HOST_IP>'
    networks:
      - gitlab_network

networks:
  gitlab_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue? Do I need to change something in my compose file.
Just an headsup, I have 100+GB of lfs objects.